# Como obter uma diferença entre duas datas?

Tags: datetime, microsoft-access, vba

Digamos que tenho uma data inicial igual à `30/01/2014 10:00` e uma data final igual à `02/02/2014 10:00`.

Gostaria de saber se é possível obter uma grade contendo estes resultados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso for possível, gostaria de saber como.

Answer (score 3):

Utilize a funcao DateDiff(). Por exemplo:

```
Dim diffDatas as Integer
diffDatas = DateDiff("d", #30/01/2012#, #31/01/2014#)
```

O primeiro parametro representa qual a medida que voce deseja calcular a diferenca, se em dias, se em meses, anos, minutos, etc. O segundo parametro contem a data inicial e o terceiro a data final.

Voce pode escolher os seguntes intervalos:

```
yyyy - Ano
q    - trimestre (quarter)
m    - Mes
y    - Dia do ano
d    - Dia
w    - Dia da semana
ww   - Semana
h    - Hora
s    - Segundos
```

Segue a referencia da funcao no site da MSDN: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Na verdade nao é so um datediff, mas sim mostrar tbm os dias que estão dentro desse intervalo

Comment: nesse caso voce precisa fazer um while da data inicial ate a data final e salvar cada data nesse intervalo num array de Datas, uma vez que o numero de dias varia de acordo com as datas iniciais e finais.

Comment: teria uma exemplo de como ficaria esse array ?

Answer (score 0):

Olá

Eu uso dessa forma

```
Dim Data_1 As Date = FormatDateTime(DtpData_Inicio.Value)

 Dim Data_2 As Date = FormatDateTime(DtpData_Fim.Value)

'Aqui, um txt traz o resultado em número decimal

TextBox1.Text += (DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, DtpData_Inicio, DtpData_Fim).ToString)
```

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 0):

Olá, mais uma sugestão.

Consiste numa classe simples que você pode reaproveitar em várias partes do seu código.

```
class DiferencaDatas
{
    public DateTime DataInicial { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataFinal { get; set; }

    public DiferencaDatas()
    {
    }

    public DiferencaDatas(DateTime dataInicial, DateTime dataFinal)
    {
        DataInicial = dataInicial;
        DataFinal = dataFinal;
    }

    //As funções retornam a diferença em minutos, horas ou dias.

    //Mostra a diferença de datas entre uma data qualquer e a data atual
    public string DifDataAtual()
    {
        TimeSpan diferenca = DateTime.Now.Subtract(DataInicial);

        if (diferenca.TotalMinutes < 60)
        {
            return $"{diferenca.TotalMinutes.ToString()} Minutos.";
        }
        else if (diferenca.TotalHours < 24)
        {
            return $"{diferenca.TotalHours.ToString("F1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)} Horas.";
        }
        else
        {
            return $"{diferenca.TotalDays.ToString("F1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)} Dias.";
        }   
    }

    //Mostra a diferfença entre duas datas qualquer
    public string DifDuasDatas()
    {
        TimeSpan diferenca = DataFinal.Subtract(DataInicial);

        if (diferenca.TotalMinutes < 60)
        {
            return $"{diferenca.TotalMinutes.ToString()} Minutos.";
        }
        else if (diferenca.TotalHours < 24)
        {
            return $"{diferenca.TotalHours.ToString("F1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)} Horas.";
        }
        else
        {
            return $"{diferenca.TotalDays.ToString("F1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)} Dias.";
        }
    }
}
```